# Jquery code to create json object inside a loop

Tags: jquery, json

http://jsfiddle.net/hU89p/219/

In the following example i have to create a json object base on the seltected checkboxes.while selecting one check box i have to create a json like

```
var data={"name":"BlackBerry Bold 9650", "rating":"2/5", "Location":UK};
```

by selecting 2 two check boxes i have to create

```
var data= {"name":"BlackBerry Bold 9650", "rating":"2/5" ,"Location":UK,"name":"Samsung Galaxy", "rating":"3.5/5", "Location":US};
```

like wise

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: what i dint get anything

Comment: Your second Javascript object is not valid, you can't repeat the same property in an object. `data` should be an array of objects.

Comment: based on the selected check boxes i have to create a json data how it is possible???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

I changed your selector to find the checked items directly.  Then, in the loop, the closest parent tr.

The appropriate values are then pulled from each td and stored in the object.  This code relies on index and can be brittle if the content changes.  You may want to use a class or other marker for the selector.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hU89p/220/)

```
function myfunc(ele) {

    var values = [];
    $.each($("input[name='case[]']:checked:enabled"),

    function () {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        values.push({
            name: $tr.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
            rating: $tr.find('td:eq(2)').text(),
            location: $tr.find('td:eq(3)').text()
        });
    });

    alert("val---" + JSON.stringify(values));
}
```

Result:

```
values = [
  {
    "name": "BlackBerry Bold 9650",
    "rating": "2/5",
    "location": "UK"
  },
  {
    "name": "Samsung Galaxy",
    "rating": "3.5/5",
    "location": "US"
  }
]
```